# Auto Renewal For Let's Encrypt with MongoDB

Tags: android, mongodb, ssl, parse-platform, lets-encrypt

I am currently setting up certificate using let's encrypt within my MongoDB installation, now I am trying to setup auto renewal, I found a guide that explains to achieve that with cronjob in nginx, here is the crontab file:

```
30 2 * * 1 /opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew >> /var/log/le-renew.log
35 2 * * 1 /etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

I noticed that nginx needs to be restarted after renewal, does this applies for mongodb as well?

Will this crontab works for mongodb?

```
30 2 * * 1 /opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew >> /var/log/le-renew.log
35 2 * * 1 /etc/init.d/mongodb restart
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If that's the way MongoDB is currently controlled, then it will work. If you are using systemd, upstart, or another supervisor, you'll have to figure out its command to restart MongoDB.